Connecting to Azure SQL Database with Entra ID and no password from Python app
I hope you can help me as I have been struggling for some days with this issue.
We have an Azure DB where we store data and through which we have some models that runs in python that interact with it. The problem is that everytime I need to run a notebook or a script I need to establish a connection with such database (where the credentials are the same of my Microsoft user account on the machine I am working on), and since the DB was set up with Microsoft Entra ID and all the "state-of-the-art" safety measures it prompts always a page where I need to insert the password to access.
This disrupts all of my workflow also because a lot of times the page doesn't pop-up and remains in the background.
I have been trying to find an alternative solution and allow Azure and my python app to communicate without having to insert the password everytime.
I tried to reproduce something of the sort: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/dev-tools/app-aad-token#--get-microsoft-entra-id-tokens-by-using-the-msal-python-library (where instead of databricks I put the ID for Azure SQL).
The idea was that I would create a Managed identity linked to the Azure SQL app and to my Microsoft account. Use that to create a token with the code above (or similar) and then with the token being able to connect to the DB without any password prompting. However, this does not seem to work as "Message: AADSTS650057" or
"Message: AADSTS100040".
Does anybody know a solution to overcome the authentication everytime?

If you want to stay developing locally you could try using a service principal. Do you have sufficient access to create a service principal and app registration in Azure? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/developer/python/sdk/authentication-overview#authentication-during-local-development

I would need this to work also in the production environment, as the app is still launched manually and requires to access with the db every time in order to load the required data. Would this be a good solution you think? The problem I have seem to me also not so unique, I am surprised that it's clear from the ms resources how to find a smooth solution..

In the "production environment" do you want to authenticate using the desktop user's identity, or a fixed application identity?  Do you have a way to securely store a client secret or certificate for a service principal?

After rereading your description it's you want to utilise the current user credentials, not a service principal. You still need to create an "entperprise application" for this. This is the correct "production" way to do it. I suggest you first investigate the viability / possibility of this in your company

Thank guys, your comments were very helpful! I ended using Azure CLI to do the job :)
